# How to hide view when animation done in android?

Tags: android, animation

I have a simple `LinearLayout` with two Buttons side by side.  They are supposed to slide into and out of view from the right side of the screen when needed.  I have the animation working and the rest of the work is done, but I have one last problem to solve.

How can I set the `LinearLayout`'s visibility to `View.GONE` after the slide out animation is complete?  I need it to disappear once it's of screen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Grab a reference of your `Animation` object doing the animation. Call `Animation#setAnimationListener` and in the listener's `onAnimationEnd` method set the visibility to `View.GONE`.

Comment: If `setFillAfter()` is true, this will fail? Since the View state after animation was visible, so it will fail to hide because `setFillAfter()` is saying hold that state. I am doing this, and my view is still visible, somehow I need to have `setFillAfter()` true because of the position.

Comment: `view.clearAnimation()` before using `setVisibility(View.GONE)` if you need `setFillAfter(true)`

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606533/3717188

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
  }           
  @Override
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
  }           
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout al = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutid);  
al.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
```

Add the above code in your

```
onAnimationEnd(){
}
```