# End animation event android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a fadeout animation in a view (which is inside a fragment), and everytime the animation happens, after it finishes the view redraws itself again. I found a work around doing `view.SetVisibility(View.GONE)` . But it doesn't wait for the animation to finish. I would like to execute this setVisibility code only after the animation has finished. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Post your code how you are showing the animation....

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can add Animation listener to your animation object like

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to prevent the fadeout animation to start again while the animation is in progress, use `if (!anim.hasStarted() || anim.hasEnded())` to detect if the animation is still running.

Answer (score 48):

Functionally the same as the accepted answer but in a much more concise way:

```
// Add/Remove any animation parameter
theView.animate()
        .alpha(0)
        .setDuration(2000)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                theView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Clear and one-liner. Top answer! Can be simplyfied with the use of lambda `.withEndAction(() -> theView.setVisibility(View.GONE));`

Comment: Keep in mind that this is API level 16 (4.1) and above.

Comment: Amazing solution, my friend. Thank you!

Comment: Important info:- 
The action is only run if the animation ends normally, if the ViewPropertyAnimator is canceled during that animation, the runnable will not run.

Comment: Works like a charm, also when using navigation component in the runnable. (Animation listener alwys crashed when I was navigating with the nav component.)

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for awhile!

Comment: Use this way. Much efficient:)

Answer (score 10):

Simply take your animation object and add animation listener to it. 
Here is the example code :

```
rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

**// WRITE HERE WHATEVER YOU WANT ON THE COMPLETION OF THE ANIMATION**


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also achieve this using [Animation.setFillAfter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 7):

Example for Kotlin

```
var fadeOutImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.fade_out_Image)
    val fadeOutAnimation = R.anim.fade_out_animation
    val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, fadeOutAnimation)
    fadeOutImage.startAnimation(animation)

    animation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
//                not implemented
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {
//                not implemented
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
            fadeOutImage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    })
```

Comment: you might save some lines using `fade_out_Image.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100L).withEndAction {fade_out_Image.visibility = View.GONE}.start()`

Comment: Comment : it is mandatory use fadeOutImage.startAnimation(animation) and not fadeOutImage = animation