# Wait for animate().translationY(-600).setDuration(300); to finish before running the next line of code

Tags: java, android

I wrote some code which makes a view in my app appear by sliding down, I now want to run an additional animation for it to slide back up, and then set the visibility of that view to `GONE`.
If I try to do that with the following code it would just set the visibility to `GONE` without running the animation.

```
if (!isTopSheetVisible) {
    pageCover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    topSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    topSheet.setTranslationY(-600);
    topSheet.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(300);
    isTopSheetVisible = true;
} else {
    topSheet.animate().translationY(-600).setDuration(300);
    pageCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    topSheet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    isTopSheetVisible = false;
}
```

I tried setting a delay using `Thread.sleep` and `TimeUnit.sleep`, and all it did was just delaying the following lines of code, the animation still would not run.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606498/end-animation-event-android