# trying to animate a button after another one finishes android

Tags: android

I'm new to android, I thought I'll try creating a mini-game (Symon Says)
I want to show the user the pattern by making the buttons blink.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to make the buttons blink one after another, currently, they all blink at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this link answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606533/13083841

Comment: I've tried using the AnimationListener, either I'm not sure how to do so, or it does not work