# How to hide textview after animation

Tags: java, android

I want to click the `Button` it will show the `TextView`is visible(perform slidedown animation), then want to click the button again it will perform another animation(slideup). after that don't need to show the `TextView`.
How do i fix it? 
please anyone have an answer to help me.

```
bclickss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean visible;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( visible = !visible) {
            tv2.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
            tv2.startAnimation(anim);
                }
            else {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
                tv2.startAnimation(anim);
                tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide view when animation done in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223867/how-to-hide-view-when-animation-done-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this before `startAnimation`

```
if (tv2.animation != null) tv2.animation.setAnimationListener(null)//needed not in all cases
tv2.clearAnimation()

anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
      tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
  });
  tv2.startAnimation(anim);
```

In second animation you need something like this:

```
if (tv2.animation != null) tv2.animation.setAnimationListener(null)//needed not in all cases
tv2.clearAnimation()

anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
      tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
  });
  tv2.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: You need to show the view on start of animation, updated answer.

Comment: updated answer, you need to clear animation and remove previous AnimationListener because it will execute `onAnimationEnd` if you'll not set it to null

Comment: Thankyou @zhebzhik,Working Fine.

Comment: Found solution in my old code. You can set it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this:
   //You can add Animation listener to your animation object like

    anim .setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

     tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `clearAnimation` before setting the visibility to `View.GONE`

```
anim .setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
         tv2.clearAnimation();
         tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. Please follow below lines:

```
Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);
Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);
```

for making view visible :

```
 view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 view.startAnimation(slide_down);
```

for hiding it:

```
view.startAnimation(slide_up);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If works please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion for you to use YOYO Animation lib for android.
It provide verious animations along with call back methods so you can hide your textview once your animation get finished in call back

[check here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)